# I have irregular java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method issues in complex multi module project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Basically, it starts with me making some refactoring like moving the extension to another file, then I get an exception of this type in some place of code at runtime and I have to find the right module and delete manually the build folder.

If any has some more insights or a better solution would be nice.

I use gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=false
```

Setting configuration-cache=true makes this issue frequent.

Answer (score 0):

So after more struggle I have found THE **Solution** :

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -name 'build' -exec rm -fr {} +
```

This will delete all build sub folders, something one would expect from running `gradle clean`.

Now I can even use `org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true` to speed up builds, I had issues anyway and now I can run this custom `clean.sh` that works as clean should.

EDIT:
So this doesn't work mostly, what I do lately is that I comment out code that is failing run app and the add it back again run and it works. Really bad issue that slows me, I would like to find real solution and somehow don't see anyone reporting this.